# When using nsIXMLHttpRequest to post to server, what does the POST payload look like?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

After much wrangling and experimenting, and with gracious help from @nmaier and @canuckistani, I was able to construct a way of `POST`ing data from within a Firefox Addon (SDK) to a web server running in `node.js` (using `express` `app.post()` to fetch `POST`ed data). It looks like this:

```
var { Cc, Cu, Ci, Cr, Cm, components } = require('chrome');
var oReq = Cc["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIXMLHttpRequest);

oReq.open('POST', targetURL);
oReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
oReq.onreadystatechange = function() 
{
    // readyState and status status handlers here...
};

oReq.send({ data : aURIEncodedString }); // object variant
```

and, also

```
oReq.send( aURIEncodedString );          // string variant
```

I tried two ways of `POST`ing my data: as a (`encodeURIComponent`-encoded) string and as an object with just one key-value pair.

At the server end is a `node.js` app, that grabs the `POST`ed data and does stuff with it. Unfortunately, I can't get that to work because I can't seem to extract the data from the `POST`. It looks like this:

```
app.post('/grab/:fid', function(request, response)              
{
    var filename = request.param('fid');
    var dataURL = request.body.data; // (and also just "request.body")
    ...
    ...
}
```

So here I use `express` middleware, with `app.VERB` (`POST` in this case) to receive the data `POST`ed from the client. Up to here works fine: the `targetURL` from the client side does properly point here and is captured here, this code is executed, the parameter (`filename`) is extracted fine.

But I can't get the actual `POST`ed payload. I tried both a string and an object, as I say, and neither results in anything; I get an empty `dataURL` variable (`{ }` or `undefined`).

The data I'm trying to send is a string created by the `toDataURL()` function of the HTML 5 `canvas` object; it's a base64-encoded string representing an image. So it's a plain ASCII string with a couple of extra symbols, which is encoded with the JavaScript `encodeURIComponent` function. So far the size is fairly small (I though that might be a problem, but I'm sending around 3K currently - though I do want to send bigger strings - up to a couple hundred Kb or so in length).

Normally in `node.js`, you use `request.body.<key-name>` when extracting data from a `POST` sent as an object where `key-name` is the key for the data-value being sent. I have a few other instances of this kind of logic in the app, and they all work fine (with the key differences being that the `POST` is done via jQuery, and is *not* done from within the Extension but within a regular Web page. For example,

```
$.post("http://mydomain.herokuapp.com/queue", 
{ 
    URL     : URL, 
    Title   : URLTitle,
    ToWhom  : ID 
}).done(function(data) .....
```

with

```
app.post('/queue', function(request, response)
{
    DB.myShopping(request.body.ToWhom, request.body.Title, request.body.URL, ....
```

and this works perfectly.

So I need to know how the `nsIXMLHttpRequest` version packages data to be `POST`ed, and how I need to construct the receiver at the server end to capture the data being `POST`ed. If anyone has ideas, I would be most appreciative to know about them.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, first of all, let's have a look at what `$.post()` produces:

```
$.post("/", { 
    URL     : "test &&", 
    Title   : "ting",
    ToWhom  : "this" 
});
```

Sends the following request:

```
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 38

URL=test+%26%26&Title=ting&ToWhom=this
```

No, lets first see what the [`request`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/request.html) module (that for some reason you still ignore) would send:

```
Request({
    url: "http://example.org/",
    content: { 
        URL     : "test &&", 
        Title   : "ting",
        ToWhom  : "this" 
    },
    onComplete: function (response) {
        console.log("complete");
    }
  }
).post();
```

Response:

```
Content-Type:   application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 38

URL=test+%26%26&Title=ting&ToWhom=this
```

Bingo!

Now, if you still would like to use `nxIXMLHttpRequest` against better advice, then you need to encode your data properly yourself, maybe with the help of the [`querystring`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/querystring.html) module:

```
var { Cc, Cu, Ci, Cr, Cm, components } = require('chrome');
const {stringify:querystring} = require("sdk/querystring");
var oReq = Cc["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIXMLHttpRequest);
oReq.open('POST', "http://example.org");
oReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
data = querystring({ 
    URL     : "test &&", 
    Title   : "ting",
    ToWhom  : "this" 
});
oReq.send(data);
```

Comment: Yeah seriously, just use the request module. It does the right thing!!

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying to your thorough response (thank you for this, @nmaier).

However, I have some issues with this. First, you use in your example a section of code that I included in my original post - __code that worked__ (it was toward the bottom of my post). I was more interested in the functionality which i had trouble with, but your response did not address that.

Secondly, there's no need to chastise me with comments such as "__against better advice__" or "__(that for some reason you still ignore)__". What I was doing was not wrong, and I'll explain in the next comment.

Comment: Both you and @canuckistani insist that I use the `request` module. But I fail to see how that's an improvement in my approach of using `nxIXMLHttpRequest`. 

Let's look at the source code for `request`. First, `request.js` has this: `const { XMLHttpRequest } = require("./net/xhr");` and then defines `xhr = source.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();`. In `xhr.js`, we first see that it's tagged as `module.metadata = { "stability": "unstable" };` Then, we see `const { Cc, Ci } = require("chrome");` followed by

Comment: `var XMLHttpRequest = exports.XMLHttpRequest = function XMLHttpRequest() { var req = Cc["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIXMLHttpRequest);`

So, please tell me how my approach is different from using `request`, when in fact the identical code is being used. Granted, `request` has some option validation and a few other things, but the core of the code in `request` and `/net/xhr` is identical to mine. So unless I'm missing something very obvious, I don't see how using `request`, against better advice or otherwise, is an improvement on what I've coded.

Comment: All this said, thank you again for taking the time to reply and illustrate clearly your thinking. That I do appreciate, even if our approaches differ. Also, I did finally get this working, and there was one clue in your response that led me to the solution.